# Can dragon fruit get scale?

Tags: identification, diseases

I think that my dragon fruit has scale. This is my first encounter with scale so I want to check first. I assume that any plant can get scale. When researching it I never saw it mentioned on cacti so I was surprised when I saw it on the dragon fruit. Is this scale? If not, what is it?

Location: Phoenix, Arizona

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To answer one part of the question; yes, cactus do get scale. Cochineal - Dactylopius coccus is the most famous. They were/are used to make carmine dye and only eat Opuntias. That doesn't appear to be your issue, though. There several other scale insects that affect cactus.

Answer (score 5):

it doesn't look like scale insects to me, they aren't regular enough, looks like some sort of injury or disease...

if they are scale insects you could pull them off and you could see "bug parts"

Comment: I agree, not like scale,but the concentric growth rings are a good indicator for a virus/fungus/bacteria

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is anthracnose, a fungal infection to which these plants are prone - so far, apart from some vague information regarding using calcium chloride as a preventative, or as a treatment on the fruits, I'm unable to find information on possible treatment. If I find anything, I'll add it later. As you've two of these plants, if the other one is infection free, you might want to consider removing this one before it spreads to the healthy one. I'm also curious as to whether this plant is the one that's got sap dripping round it from the mesquite, or whether it's the one that hasn't.

UPDATE: You've said this is the one that hasn't got sap dripping on it, so I'm wondering whether the healthy one has not succumbed fully to infection because of the calcium content in the dripping sap... it's a possibility, but not one I can confirm. Might be worth supplying extra calcium to this unhealthy, infected plant, but I suspect its too late to make much difference.

Comment: Good question @Bamboo - those images are from the less healthy non-sap-dripping of the two Dragon fruit. The other (health) one has a couple of those but most of it is on the unhealthy looking one. I should also add that they are two different types of Dragon Fruit. One is white and the other red although neither have produced fruit to date. I'll add that information to the other question.

Comment: I'm researching what is needed to improve the soil around these plants and plan on doing that soon. I was going to add some peat moss to increase the soil acidity. What would you suggest to increase the calcium?

Comment: @Guy - to be honest, I'd have a look round whatever you call garden centres where you are, in the chemicals bit, or ask for advice. Calcium chloride kills plants if overused and can cause problems in humans, but I'd imagine any product available off the shelf is less likely to cause such problems. If you want a quick, acidifying treatment, get some chelated iron tonic (its called Sequestrene here, no idea what it might be where you are). Be interesting to see if it has any impact on the plant's coloration.